# javascript: Adding a class to an element that has no ID

Tags: javascript, css, class, dojo

Is there a way to add a class to an element (using pure javascript) that does not have an ID, but has some existing classes? If I had:

```
<div class="rightAlign pushDown">...</div>
```

How could I add a class to make it like this

```
 <div class="rightAlign pushDown redOutline">...</div>
```

This is just a simple example. The reason for adding another class and not changing the original class in CSS or changing the class altogether with javascript is that I am dealing with elements created by Dojo. I just need to access something that has no convenient ID to grab a hold of.

Keep in mind I am working in javascript and Dojo, I can not use jQuery at all...

Comment: what version of dojo? see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/addClass.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dojo way would be as:

```
dojo.query(".rightAlign.pushDown").addClass("redOutline");
```

This will add the class to add elements with those two classes

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something just like this!

Comment: As a followup question, could removeClass be used the same way?

Comment: Yes you can use it too. There is also dojo.toggleClass if you want something that automatically adds or removes depending if its there. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/toggleClass.html

Answer (score 3):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("existing_class");
elements[0].className += " new_class";
```

If you want to add a class to all elements with a specified class then use a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    elements[i].className =+ " new_class";
}
```

I think `getElementsByClassName` doesn't work in old IE versions though.

**EDIT:**
[Polyfill](http://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607) for IE support

Comment: Keep in mind that getElementsByClassName() doesn't return an array, rather an HTMLCollection.

Comment: Thanks, both of the answers work like a charm. I am accepting the dojo answer because it is simpler but if anyone is not using dojo, this answer works well, including the polyfill for IE support.